# How to use href="#" with routing module Angular2+?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I have a navbar component working as sideNav. For expand it, I need to click in a link which is marked as a "href="#"" like the example above:

```
<nav>
  <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
      <li>
        <div class="user-view teal lighten-2">
          <a href="#!user"><img class="circle" src="images/yuna.jpg"></a>
          <a href="#!name"><span class="white-text name">John Doe</span></a>
          <a href="#!email"><span class="white-text email">jdandturk@gmail.com</span></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>First Link With Icon</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!">Second Link</a></li>
      <li><div class="divider"></div></li>
      <li><a class="subheader">Subheader</a></li>
      <li><a class="waves-effect" href="#!">Third Link With Waves</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a materialize="sideNav" href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse show-on-large"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>     
</nav>
```

The code works fine, but when I've implemented the routing module, the system is trying to navigate to this route, I imagine. What is the best solution for this link continues working with the routing module?

The routing module is like that:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NaoAutorizadoComponent } from './core/nao-autorizado.component';
import { PaginaNaoEncontradaComponent } from './core/pagina-nao-encontrada.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'inicial', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'nao-autorizado', component: NaoAutorizadoComponent },
  { path: 'pagina-nao-encontrada', component: PaginaNaoEncontradaComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pagina-nao-encontrada' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In this case, when I try to click in a link href="#", the system is redirecting to the "pagina-nao-encontrada", thats means, "page not found"

Comment: is inicial a component?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't import the correct module, now it's working ok

Comment: you would rather use routerLink rather than href

Comment: you are right, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't related to routing module, but I didn't import the MaterializeModule in my NavbarComponent, now it's working well.